# JSX components are not rendered when run electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, babeljs

I am a beginner with Electron and React. I tried to make an electron app with react but JSX components are not rendered although CSS file rendered well.
I used babel to convert the JSX component to pure javascript but still not rendered. I don't know where is the problem, can anyone explain what I should do?

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.
    }

    "main": "dist/electron.js"
    "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run babel && electron .",
    "babel": "babel ./src --out-dir ./dist --copy-files"
     }

     "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1"
    }
```

My `.babelrc` is:

```
    {"plugins": 
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
    }
```

My `electron.js` file is:

```js
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

    let mainWindow;

    function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 800,
    icon: "./dist/img/icon.png",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile("./dist/index.html");

    mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
    });
    }

    app.on("ready", createWindow);

    app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
    }
    });

    app.on("activate", () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
    }
    });
```

My HTML file is

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/index.css" />
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Resala Naser</title>
     </head>

     <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
       <script type="text/bable" src="../dist/index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My `index.js` file is:

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css"; 
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    import App from "./components/App";

    window.onload = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    };
```

[My project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjwC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick list:

1. Take a look at [electron sample](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) for a simple structure.
2. You're importing css files inside js files, without webpack that will not work so either set up webpack in project or simply remove css imports and add them in html file.
3. you're importing the index.js file in html but with the wrong path, they're in the same directory

So after the changes your files would look like the following:

components/App:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return <h1>this works</h1>
    }
}
```

electron.js

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file:///${__dirname}/index.html`);
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

app.on("activate", function() {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/index.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Resala Naser</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import "./index.css";
// import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "./components/App";

window.onload = () => {
  console.log("this thing ");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
};
```